# Using JavaScript to prevent email address to be used by bots

Tags: javascript, html, email, bots

Do you think that a bot will be able to send mails to the email address mentioned on the page in HTML?

Here is my code :

```
<h6 class="text-gray">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var email = 'gmail.com';

        email = ('blabla.blibli' + '@' + email);

        document.write('<a href="mailto:' + email + '">' + email + '</a>');
    </script>
    <noscript>

        L'adresse mail est protégée par Javascript

    </noscript>
</h6>
```

Comment: depends on whether bot process script or not...there is no straightforward answer. Better to  put obfuscated  address in dom and parse it when user clicks

Comment: you're much better off using a form in your site that emails you server-side as opposed to publicly displaying email addresses, if you can.  Just be sure to use proper methods to avoid spam bot submissions (captcha's, honeypots) and implement methods to avoid things like SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably won't help at all. Most bots scrape pages that are fully rendered. Your JavaScript will add the email address to the page when it is rendered.

So the HTML that is seen by the browser (or in this case the bot) already contains the email address at the right place, unobfuscated. It will be easy to read.

They do not have to "parse" your JavaScript `script` block to get to the information.

Comment: OK, I think I will use a picture with e-mail address on. Then it will be OK.

Comment: @Kuartz I do not think this will help you much either. It is easy for bots to read those images as well. Bots will use a mechanism called _Optical image recognition_ to read the text from the image. Sounds fancy, but is easy. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Comment: Mhhhhh. OK. So I won't put any e-mail address on this website. Il will propose to the user to send an e-mail directly with a form using PHPmailer. Thanks for help.